# Where should i store score variable?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I'm working on my multiplayer game. The game is about pvp, you can shoot your friends and all stuff like that. I decided to make a score widget, which would show who is better. You might have seen something similar to what I'm talking about in fps games like csgo, valorant, overwatch, etc. [image] Everyone should see the score.

I tried storing variables on servers character pawn. But pawn can be destroyed and score rollbacks to 0:0.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For replicated data that is persistent to respawn, you have two main options with the built-in game framework:

1. Create your own subclass of `AGameState` and the replicated data you want in it. There is one Game state and it is replicated on all clients. See what [the official wiki](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Framework/GameMode/) (bottom of the page) says about GameState. You can store game-related data in it as total kill count in team deathmatches or team capture points in domination matches.
2. Create your own subclass of `APlayerState` and the replicated data you want in it. There is one Player state per player and it is replicated on all clients. See [the official API](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APlayerState/) of `APlayerState`. You can store each players' kill count in it for example or the number of objective a player captured. Make sure data is fed from the server and replicated to clients and not the other way around.

Unreal Engine comes with a powerful [Game Framework](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Framework/), make sure to get familiar with it.